# Would it be possible to create a gel, holding viruses, that could alter the human genome when rubbed in?

Tags: gene-expression, human-genetics, hair

I was wondering if it could be possible to engineer a virus, that when it comes into contact with human hair follicles, it could alter someones natural hair color. 
Naturally blue hair anyone?

Doubtless there are loads of problems, but i was hoping they could be identified and potentially worked around.

Comment: You might take a look at [Topical Gene Delivery](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=topical+gene+delivery) on pubmed, but this also has papers that deliver to the eye, and any in vivo gene delivery is really hard right now. Also, blue pigment is not something you could easily make biologically. Blue birds use [light interference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_coloration) to get their color.

Comment: So, i would need to somehow engineer biological microstructures, in order to reflect only a blue wavelength?                                                                          And when you speak of birds, you refer to plumage coloration, while i'm asking about hair specifically. There are some mammalian species that have blue or bluish hair. I'm wondering how to adapt that to a human.

Comment: Mamalian species with dye colored blue hair? I doubt that. This is probably some light effect.

Comment: Cats and rats can have a color that is classified as "blue", but it really looks more grey. Behold: http://messybeast.com/colour-charts.htm